# microphone buffer becomes 0 after device back key press in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, button, microphone, back

i have a microphone object to record sound. My byte buffer array gives me correct result if i am on the same xaml file.

But once i press the back key and come to same page again, the buffer contains 0 in every array member.

In constructor, i have the following code:

```
this.microphone.GetData(buffer);
```

In a button click handler, i have the following code:

```
// Stop previously running microphone
if (this.microphone.State == MicrophoneState.Started)
{
    this.microphone.Stop();
}

// Clear previous content of microphone

this.microphone.BufferDuration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);

this.microphone.Start();

// Store recorded audio
 this.buffer = new byte[this.microphone.GetSampleSizeInBytes(this.microphone.BufferDuration)];
```

Is there any problem with using microphone class? Does it get cleared or what after coming from a device back button press?

Thanks in advance. Please let me know if there is any doubt in the question.

Comment: can you show where this code is located with regard to the pages you're navigating between

Answer (score 0):

If you start a microphone on a page then navigate away backwards from it, that page will be destroyed, along with any buffered recording. When you next navigate to that page a new instance of it will be created along with a new microphone (and stream/buffer).

Is this your scenario?

If I were you I'd create the microphone at application level so it doesn't risk being impacted by navigation between pages in the app.